# Selecting Huge number of records using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to load a fact table. I am joining 7 different tables. When I select the count(1) from that join, it took 25 minutes to execute and returned 988368728 records. On top of that I am using group by and again joining with the same set of tables.

Example:

```
Select set1.minVal, t2b, t2.Key1, T3.Key2... t7.g From t1, t2,...,t7
left outer join
(
    Select 
        Min(t1a) minVal, Max(t2b) maxVal, t2.Key1, T3.Key2 From t1, t2,...,t7
    group by t2.Key1, K3.Key2(Key Columns)
)set1
on t2.Key1 = set1.Key1
and t3.Key2 = set1.Key2
and t2b = maxVal
```

When I execute the above query it was failed after 1 hour due to in sufficient memory for TEMPDB. I need to use this query in SSSI Package to load a fact table. I can have options to write query to achieve this through different ways. One of them is I can use an SP to divide and conquer the result, I can use SSIS Package to divide and conquer but, I don't know how to break it.

I need help to sort out this time killer.

Answer (score 4):

Your query:

```
Select set1.minVal, t2b, t2.Key1, T3.Key2... t7.g From t1, t2,...,t7
```

and the sub-query

```
Min(t1a) minVal, Max(t2b) maxVal, t2.Key1, T3.Key2 From t1, t2,...,t7
```

Is doing a cartesian product on 7 (presumably) table, where every row in `t1` is matched with every row in `t2`, which is matched with every row in `t3`, etc.

Without knowing what you want it's hard to give an answer, however I suspect you need either 7 different sub-queries or you need to join the 7 tables together somehow.

Comment: I am sure I've got 98 mils before group by, it reduced to 35 mils after group by. I want a way to divide and conquer the query. Either in Store Procedure or SSIS Package.

Comment: My point is are you _supposed_ to have a Cartesian join or are there key columns between the tables that you should use to reduce the # or records?  Also you're only using values from 4 of the 7 tables

Comment: To put it another way.... how did you come up with this query because it appears to be incorrect - it's creating a cartesian join which always will result in a TEMPDB error if you're using large tables. You need to analyse your query and come up with the correct query. Yours is almost definitely incorrect.

Comment: This logic may be incorrect but the approach is same. Our BA has given this logic to load the data.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm with the other guys regarding the Cartesian join. It's such a rare use case and with even medium datasets can result in a lot of data. If this query can't be optimist, you're going to need to throw more metal at it.

Comment: @HRK so tell your BA to validate that the logic is correct, and if it is, that the hardware you have won't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Load each table into a staging area on the target database via data flow tasks, then use an Execute SQL task to perform the join and insert into the fact table using TSQL.